# How to solve a challenge to authorize my domain for letsencrypt?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to authorize my domain for letsencrypt. Previously, a few months ago on a different server, I didn't it, now I do for some reason.

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/home/deployer/pfios -d my_website.com -d www.my_website.com
Failed authorization procedure. my_website.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: The key authorization file from the server did not match this challenge [fdsfs-fdsfdsf.fdsfdsfds333] != [gangnam style!]


Domain: www.my_website.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: The key authorization file from the server did not match
   this challenge
   [fdsfs-fdsfdsf.fdsfdsfds333]
   != [gangnam style!]
```

The code for authorization or rather the name of a file is different each time. Where should I actually retrieve it? In this case it's "fdsfs-fdsfdsf.fdsfdsfds"

Answer (score 2):

Try authorize your domain via standalone webserver from LE.

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a standalone -d my_website.com -d www.my_website.com
```

You must remember - when you generate new cert you must off your main webserver (Apache, nginx, etc.)

Comment: "off your main webserver", please clarify

Answer (score 0):

In my case solved it by running
`sudo apt-get update` and then running the renew command

```
/usr/bin/letsencrypt renew
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have IPV6 redirection configured in your DNS provider. 
If the redirection does not redirect to your server, remove it.